# What's the replacement for the deprecated @Persister in Hibernate 6.2?

Tags: hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have an Agency entity and a Role entity, Agencies are grouped into various types. Each agency type is associated with a collection of Roles. This agency type to roles association is stored in the following association table:

```
AGENCY_TYPE_ROLE table:
   AGENCY_TYPE_ID integer not null,
   ROLE_ID integer not null,
   (AGENCY_TYPE_ID, ROLE_ID) primary key,
```

My goal is that when an agency is deleted, the rows in the AGENCY_TYPE_ROLE table must not be deleted for the corresponding agency type.

Prior to Hibernate 6.2.0, per the Hibernate documentation and this blog https://blog.termian.dev/posts/jpa-readonly-jointable/, I achieved my goal using the @Persister annotation with a custom ReadOnlyCollectionPersister class:

```
@Table(name = "AGENCY", schema = "TEST")
public class Agency {

  private Set<Role> roles;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(
      name = "AGENCY_TYPE_ROLE",
      schema = "TEST",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "AGENCY_TYPE_ID"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID"))
  @Persister(impl= ReadOnlyCollectionPersister.class)
  public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return (roles == null ? null : roles);
  }

  public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
  }
}
```

where ReadOnlyCollectionPersister is a custom class:

```
public class ReadOnlyCollectionPersister extends BasicCollectionPersister {
  private static Collection asInverse(Collection collection) {
    collection.setInverse(true);
    return collection;
  }

  public ReadOnlyCollectionPersister(
      Collection collectionBinding,
      CollectionDataAccess cacheAccessStrategy,
      RuntimeModelCreationContext creationContext) throws MappingException,
      CacheException {
    super(asInverse(collectionBinding), cacheAccessStrategy, creationContext);
  }
}
```

In Hibernate 6.2, the @Persister is deprecated with the following notes in the documentation --

*2.4.10. Define a custom entity persister

Supplying a custom persister has been allowed historically, but has never been fully supported. Hibernate 6 provides better, alternative ways to accomplish the use cases for a custom persister. As of 6.2 @Persister has been formally deprecated.*

I have not been able to find an alternative way to accomplish my goal in Hibernate 6.2 without using the @Persister. Any insights and/or suggestions?

I searched and experimented various approaches and have not been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding but your persister seems to be mutating the `org.hibernate.mapping.Collection` i.e. the metadata of your mapping. In case you really need to do that it would probably be better to mutate it during the Hibernate startup.

The JPA javadoc for the `ManyToMany` annotation says:

> Every many-to-many association has two sides, the owning side and the
> non-owning, or inverse, side. The join table is specified on the
> owning side. If the association is bidirectional, either side may be
> designated as the owning side. If the relationship is bidirectional,
> the non-owning side must use the mappedBy element of the ManyToMany
> annotation to specify the relationship field or property of the owning
> side.

So it looks to me like you want `Agency` to be the non-owning side and your mapping could be:

```
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy="agencies")
  public Set<Role> getRoles() {
```

Comment:  Also, if it's really necessary to mutate the mapping model, based off of annotations of the domain model, Hibernate 6 offers some extension points for doing that in `org.hibernate.binder`.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I oversimplified my use case and that may have caused the confusion. My apology. I edited my question.

Comment: Try `AttributeBinder` + `@AttributeBinderType`. I'm not promising it will work, but it _might_.